# callback not firing on pageload - jquery easy tab plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using this plugin for tabs - https://github.com/JangoSteve/jQuery-EasyTabs

In turn, it uses this plugin for it's hash changes - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

I've set it up by doing the following -

```
$('#tab-container').easytabs().bind('easytabs:after', function(evt, tab, panel, data) {
   alert('DO SOMETHING!')
});
```

This results in an alert being called when a tab is clicked.

The issue that I'm having is that the call back is not firing on page load.

If I visit  - www.mitesite.com#mytabid -  the plugin will read the hash value in the url and set the correct tab, but it will not fire the callback.

Any idea how I should fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could trigger the `onhashchange` event on page load. This will ensure that whatever function is bound to your hashchange event will be fired on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).trigger("onhashchange");
});
```

Comment: That is **not** how you should be posting on SO. Read the FAQ please.